# ruby gem not found although it is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I found some similar problems here on SO, but none seem to match my case (sorry if I overlooked). Here's my problem: I installed oauth-plugin gem to ruby gems dir, but trying to use it in rails app tells me that it's not being found. Here's the output of relevant commands:

Installation

```
% s gem install oauth-plugin
Successfully installed oauth-plugin-0.3.14
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for oauth-plugin-0.3.14...
Installing RDoc documentation for oauth-plugin-0.3.14...
```

`gem which oauth-plugin` output:

```
% gem which oauth-plugin
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/oauth-plugin-0.3.14/lib/oauth-plugin.rb
```

`gem env` output:

```
% gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/eimantas/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :gem => ["--no-ri", "--no-rdoc"]
     - :sources => ["http://gems.ruby.lt/", "http://rubygems.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.ruby.lt/
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Doing `ls -l /usr/lib/ruby` shows this:

```
% ls -l /usr/lib/ruby     
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Aug 14  2009 /usr/lib/ruby -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby
```

And the gem in question is in intended location.

Here's the error that rails give me when I try running `$ rake spec`

```
Missing these required gems:
  oauth-plugin   = 0.3.14

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.173 at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.6 at /Users/eimantas/.gem/ruby/1.8, /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8, /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

This is not a single gem that is not being found by rubygems (although it's located where it should be). Any guidance towards the solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the error message that Rails is giving you?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have two different versions of Ruby installed. First is in:

/usr/bin/ruby

and second one is in:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby

The problem is that one is used in command line (i.e. to install gems) and another is used by web server to run Rails.

Since your web server is using second Ruby version one solution would be to install gem using that Ruby version. Alternatively, you can tell your web server to use different Ruby version - depending on which server you are using this can be achieved in different ways.

Comment: You can most likely do something like: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem install oauth-plugin to install gem using web server Ruby version.

Comment: from the ls -l /usr/lib/ruby it seems that the two versions you are talking about are the same

Comment: You are right. These two folders have different ruby installed: `% /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-darwin10.2.0] 
% /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 173) [universal-darwin10.0]`

So if I remove the one in `Ruby.framework` and put a symlink to the first one I should be good.

Comment: Could you add the gem to your gemfile for the rails app and run bundle?

Answer (score 4):

Just try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

and select the other ruby version. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you previously install oauth?

```
gem install oauth
```

It seems it's [needed](http://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin)

**EDIT:**

On your

```
gem env
```

you have

```
RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
```

But if you look at the error it says you are running

```
ruby 1.8.7.173
```

Are you pointing to different versions of ruby?

Comment: hmm.. this must be the cause although I don't understand why gem command installs the gem in one location and then ruby on rails takes different one (I'm certain I have only one version of ruby in my system).

Comment: what about "sudo" gem install? Does he have two differents GEM_HOME?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: Do you have a `config.gem 'oauth-plugin'` line in your `config/environment.rb` file?

If so, try running `script/console` and type `system("gem which oauth-plugin")`

Its possible your gem path is messed up from inside your rails app. The above command should tell you if the gem is actually being found by rails.

If it isn't found try `system("gem env")` from the `script/console` and see if anything jumps out at you. This should help with debugging.

Comment: I have config.gem 'oauth-plugin' in my environment.rb, but when that line is present - i can't run ./script/console since the gem dependency is not satisifed .( But if I comment it out and run system 'gem which...' i get the correct path to the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows 7, using the rubyinstaller, I selected the second checkbox that makes ruby available everywhere, meaning you dont have to configure any paths to the ruby version you have installed. It may affect other versions of ruby or other projects if you have multiple dev environments.