# Error loading rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rspec

During an operation (rspec related) that required loading rubygems (from config/boot.rb file) I got the following error message:

```
~/config/boot.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
~/config/boot.rb:1
    from ~/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
    from ~/config/application.rb:1
    from ~/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from ~/config/environment.rb:2
    from ~/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from ~/spec/spec_helper.rb:3
    from ~/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from ~/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/options.rb:132:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/spec:3
```

I looked for this error on SO and found the following topics:
[ruby gem not found although it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797020/ruby-gem-not-found-although-it-is-installed) and 
[no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror)

However they both mentionned that the problem could come from the existance of multiple versions of ruby on the machine. Actually that was the case, so I decided to run a fresh installation of ruby and rails using RVM. But I still have the same problem!

Additional information:

```
which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby

which rails
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rails

which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/gem

gem --version
1.5.0

ls /usr/lib/ruby
1.8  1.9.1  gems
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I apparently solved my problem by using the command `rspec` instead of `spec`. If someone can explain what is actually going on behind the scene, it would be great!

```
amokrane@san-francisco ~/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/spec $ spec models/user_spec.rb 
/home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/config/boot.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/config/boot.rb:1
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/config/application.rb:1
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/config/environment.rb:2
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/spec/spec_helper.rb:3
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/options.rb:132:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/spec:3

amokrane@san-francisco ~/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/forecaster/spec $ rspec models/weather_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) Weather should be valid
     Failure/Error: @weather = Weather.new
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'weathers'
     # ./models/weather_spec.rb:6:in `new'
     # ./models/weather_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.11124 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Comment: which version of rspec are you trying to use? `spec` was deprecated, so you might trying to use an older version of rspec.

Comment: Good :) I'd attempt to remove any old rspec gems if you have any installed.