# Cannot find bundler gem for a Jekyll blog

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

I'm trying to setup a new Jekyll site and am running into issues after I create a new site using `jekyll new testSite`.

I get an error saying:

```
New jekyll site installed in /Users/myPath.
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have bundler or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- bundler' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  bundler
```

I've installed bundler already using `gem install bundler`, but it can't seem to find it.

`bundler -v` gives `Bundler version 1.14.2`

`jekyll -v` gives `jekyll 3.3.1`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

given that you have ruby, jekyll and blunder correctly installed. inside `testSite` folder run:

```
bundle
```

`bundle` (or `bundle install`, cf. [bundler doc](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-install.1.html)) will Install the dependencies specified in your Gemfile.

then run your new website, with:

```
bundle exec jekyll s
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I run `bundle install` and it says it installs the dependencies and gems, but when I run `bundle exec jekyll s`, it says `Could not find jekyll-feed-0.8.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.` still, so weird.

Comment: yes. looks weird :) try [bundle update](https://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-update.1.html) to  explicitly update the version of a gem. also check if you'r in a similar situation as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797020/ruby-gem-not-found-although-it-is-installed)

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked for me, in ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install ruby-bundler
```